# How to fix Error: The project seems to require yarn but it's not installed

Tags: vue.js, yarn-v2

I just create this project with,

```
npm install --global yarn
vue create elecprog
yarn serve (-> error)
```

Also, I'm using VS Code terminal

```
PS D:\elcp\elecprog> yarn serve
yarn run v1.22.17
$ vue-cli-service serve
 INFO  Starting development server...


 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2889ms                                                                                                                                                                                           오전 9:10:38


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:[port]/ 
  - Network: http://[myIp]:[port]/

 ERROR  Error: The project seems to require yarn but it's not installed.
Error: The project seems to require yarn but it's not installed.
    at checkYarn (D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\env.js:46:43)
    at exports.hasProjectYarn (D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\env.js:42:10)
    at D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:312:34
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:44:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Watching._done (D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:287:28)
    at D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:209:21
    at Compiler.emitRecords (D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:906:5)
    at D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:187:22
    at D:\elcp\elecprog\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:872:14
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS D:\elcp\elecprog>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (OS: WINDOWS 11) installing yarn form official installer: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable
form tab Alternatives

However this is only for Yarn 1.22.19 and current Yarn version you can check here:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/releases